# Google APIs and extension force install list

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome-extension, google-directory-api

I have an app on GAE in which I'm using the Google Directory API for retrieving organization units and users. I am wondering if this API or any other have the option to update the extension force install list. Currently it's done by copying links and IDs to the Google Admin Console, but I am looking for a solution (if one even exists) to have this feature implemented directly in my application.

Thanks!

Comment: For this kind of feature request issue, the best way I think is to post it on [crbug.com](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).